# How can I shorten this up?

Tags: java

I got a method that defines the season based on the input given by the user.
Ex: 1/6 = Winter
It works, but just seems like there should be an easier way to do this instead of having all this code. Any suggestions?

```
public String getSeason()
    {
        String result = "UNKNOWN";

        if (month == 1 && day >= 1)
        {
            result = "WINTER";
        }
        else if (month == 2 && day >= 1)
        {
            result = "WINTER";
        }
        else if (month == 3 && day <= 20)
        {
            result = "WINTER";
        }
        else if (month == 3 && day >= 21)
        {
            result = "SPRING";
        }
        else if (month == 4 && day >= 1)
        {
            result = "SPRING";
        }
        else if (month == 5 && day >= 1)
        {
            result = "SPRING";
        }
        else if (month == 6 && day <= 20)
        {
            result = "SPRING";
        }
        else if (month == 6 && day >= 21)
        {
            result = "SUMMER";
        }
        else if (month == 7 && day >= 1)
        {
            result = "SUMMER";
        }
        else if (month == 8 && day >= 1)
        {
            result = "SUMMER";
        }
        else if (month == 9 && day <= 22)
        {
            result = "SUMMER";
        }
        else if (month == 9 && day >= 23)
        {
            result = "FALL";
        }
        else if (month == 10 && day >= 1)
        {
            result = "FALL";
        }
        else if (month == 11 && day >= 1)
        {
            result = "FALL";
        }
        else if (month == 12 && day <= 20)
        {
            result = "FALL";
        }
        else if (month == 12 && day >= 21)
        {
            result = "FALL";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Just combine multiple tests into one: `if (month < 3 || month == 3 && day <= 20 || month == 12 && day >= 21) { result = 'WINTER'} else { ...` etc. Some tests are unnecessary, for example `month == 2 && day >= 1`.

Comment: Sorry I was playing with the code trying different options and forgot to change that part back.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `switch`.

```
switch (month) {
    case 1: case 2: /* Winter */; break;
    case 3: if (day <= 20) {/* Winter */} else {/* Spring */} break;
    case 4: case 5: /* Spring */; break;
    case 6: if (day <= 21) {/* Spring */} else {/* Summer */} break;
    // Continue the pattern...
    default: /* Unknown */; break;
}
```

This is much better than an `if-else` ladder because it is simple. The `break;` statements keep the program from "falling through" and executing each and every case.

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten it by throwing away the unnecessary `day >= 1` (what else could it be?) and combining months with the same outcome:

```
if (month <= 2 || (month == 3 && day <= 20) || (month == 12 && day >= 21)) {
    // Winter
} else if (month <= 5 || (month == 6 && day <= 21)) {
    // Spring
} else if (month <= 8 || (month == 9 && day <= 22)) {
    // Summer
} else {
    // Fall
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way of looking at the problem, using the Java Calendar class. e.g. (untested code) It's a little more complex as you nee leap year detection, but as I say, a different way to think about the problem.

```
public String testSeason(int year, int month, int day) {
    //month is 0 based!

    int FIRST_DAY_OF_SPRING = 31 + 28 + 21; // might need leap year detection to be completely accurate.
    int FRIRST_DAY_OF_SUMMER = FRST_DAY_OF_SPRING + 10 + 31 + 30 +31; 
// define FALL and WINTER similarly.

     Calendar testDate = new Calendar();
    testDate.set(year,month,day);

    if (testDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < FIRST_DAY_OF_SPRING)  return "Winter";
    if (testDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < FIRST_DAY_OF_SUMMER)  return "Spring";
// continue for rest of seasons.
}
```

Comment: Why make objects and the like and introduce all that overhead when you can solve the problem numerically?